# Transforming dataframe string categories to numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I have some columns in my dataframe that look like:

```
 total
  NaN
26-27
52-53
88-89
  165
  280
  399
  611
  962
 1407
 1937
```

I would like to transform them into numerical values using a round-up:

```
 total
  NaN
   27
   53
   89
  165
  280
  399
  611
  962
 1407
 1937
```

clearly, pd.to_numeric() does not work as 26-27 is an object. I can do it one by one, but is there an elegant and fast way to do the transformation?

Comment: Mike do you ever have columns with 59-57, that changes things

Comment: no, not in this one, but that would be interesting as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you truly need a round up between two numbers, that could be out of order, you can do this:

```
df.total.str.split('-').apply(pd.Series).astype(float).max(axis=1).astype('Int64')                                                                                                    

0      NaN
1       27
2       53
3       89
4      165
5      280
6      399
7      611
8      962
9     1407
10    1937
dtype: Int64
```

Answer (score 6):

IIUC, we can use a little bit of regex to extract all numbers grabbing the last element before a line terminator

#### Before `\n` using `$`

#### `\d+` matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

#### `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as

```
df['total'].str.extract(r'(\d+)$').astype(float)
out:
0        NaN
1       27.0
2       53.0
3       89.0
4      165.0
5      280.0
6      399.0
7      611.0
8      962.0
9     1407.0
10    1937.0
Name: total, dtype: float64
```

Comment: also a great answer

Comment: thanks @Mike I didn't think that the values would be unordered so oppressionslayer's answer makes much more sense. Happy programming!

Answer (score 2):

You can separate it according to the `-` sign and take the last element with `split`. This allows you to convert the data to `float` and then to `integer` if you like.

```py
>>> df.total.str.split('-').str[-1].astype(float)
0        NaN
1       27.0
2       53.0
3       89.0
4      165.0
5      280.0
6      399.0
7      611.0
8      962.0
9     1407.0
10    1937.0
Name: total, dtype: float64
```

Or if you want to cast to integer,

```py
>>> df.total.str.split('-').str[-1].astype(float).astype('Int64')
0      NaN
1       27
2       53
3       89
4      165
5      280
6      399
7      611
8      962
9     1407
10    1937
Name: total, dtype: Int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution with regex:

```
df.total.str.replace(r"\d+\-","").astype(float)
```